# Javafx - open login.microsoftonline.com page in webview component

Tags: windows, macos, javafx, webview, office365

I have problem with opening login.microsoftonline.com page in webview component from javafx. I have simply code that should open this page without any trouble:

```
   WebView webView = new WebView();
    WebEngine webEngine = webView.getEngine();
    var url = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/";
    webEngine.load(url);

    VBox root = new VBox();
    root.getChildren().add(webView);
    Scene scene = new Scene(root);
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();

    webEngine.getLoadWorker().stateProperty().addListener((obs, oldValue, newValue) -> { 
     System.out.println(webEngine.getLocation());
    });
```

When I try to execute this code on machine with windows operating system I receive blank page:
[image]
When I execute the same code on macbook, site is opening:
[image]

I'm using java 10 and really no idea what's wrong. Does anybody have the same issue? Any idea how to solve this problem? maybe there is other component instead of webview that I can use to do my stuff?

Comment: Try @James_D suggestion in the comments. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36541321/why-javafx-webview-failed-to-load-status-failed

Comment: I didn't receive any stacktrace, the request is build correctly and worker status is SUCCEEDED

Comment: Have you tried downloading the scripts and adding them to your project manually?

Comment: I'm not sure how it could help? I found similar issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52572853/failed-integrity-metadata-check-in-javafx-webview-ignores-systemprop and it seems that there is problem with implementation of webview/webengine in java implementation.

Comment: not a desicion also, but may be a direction. We created few project with webView on java 8 and faced multiple problems. It was really buggy. And as a result decided to switch to another technology - PhantomJS, may be it will suits your needs too, if you dont need a webview to be in an app window.

Comment: Side note: rendering web sites of identity providers "in-app" should be avoided. Please read my blog post for more information: https://puces-blog.blogspot.com/2019/07/why-apps-should-not-use-in-app.html

Answer (score 0):

This is not the solution to your problem but may lead you in the right direction. It seems that the site body is loaded using `script`. That script depends on other scripts I am guessing. It appears none of the other scripts are loading.

```
import com.sun.javafx.webkit.WebConsoleListener;
import java.security.KeyManagementException;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.security.cert.X509Certificate;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.web.WebEngine;
import javafx.scene.web.WebView;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLContext;
import javax.net.ssl.TrustManager;
import javax.net.ssl.X509TrustManager;

/**
 *
 * @author blj0011
 */
public class JavaFXApplication281 extends Application
{

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage)
    {
        try {
            TrustManager trm = new X509TrustManager()
            {
                @Override
                public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers()
                {
                    return null;
                }

                @Override
                public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] certs, String authType)
                {
                }

                @Override
                public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] certs, String authType)
                {
                }
            };

            SSLContext sc = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
            sc.init(null, new TrustManager[]{trm}, null);
            HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(sc.getSocketFactory());

            WebView webView = new WebView();
            WebEngine webEngine = webView.getEngine();
            WebConsoleListener.setDefaultListener(new WebConsoleListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void messageAdded(WebView webView, String message, int lineNumber, String sourceId)
                {
                    System.out.println("Console: [" + sourceId + ":" + lineNumber + "] " + message);
                }
            });
            webEngine.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            String url = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/";//"https://login.microsoftonline.com/jsdisabled";//
            webEngine.load(url);

            webEngine.getLoadWorker().stateProperty().addListener((obs, oldValue, newValue) -> {
                System.out.println(newValue);
                String html = (String) webEngine.executeScript("document.documentElement.outerHTML");
                System.out.println(html);
            });

            webEngine.setOnError((event) -> {
                System.out.println(event.getMessage());
            });
//        webEngine.getLoadWorker().exceptionProperty().addListener((obs, oldExc, newExc) -> {
//            if (newExc != null) {
//                newExc.printStackTrace();
//            }
//        });
            StackPane root = new StackPane();

            root.getChildren().add(webView);

            Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 250);

            primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World!");
            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.show();
        }
        catch (KeyManagementException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

Output:

```
Console: [null:0] Cannot load stylesheet https://secure.aadcdn.microsoftonline-p.com/ests/2.1.8233.17/content/cdnbundles/converged.v2.login.min_jumzhgrnvlj7lwxqltrteq2.css. Failed integrity metadata check.
Console: [https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/authorize?client_id=4345a7b9-9a63-4910-a426-35363201d503&response_mode=form_post&response_type=code+id_token&scope=openid+profile&state=OpenIdConnect.AuthenticationProperties%3d5xhL9s5iN_65agH7ctGnRfQlJHUHgSrEvD4vkaO323RyB1klBHD6Qh5qidm6GuaIHM8_GaSANKH6y1ohWHalX4QU_YyqGJqXV8wphi2TVMAAY3yyXQk3GB-yqWm0j3oh&nonce=636748812038183968.MmMxNjY2YjEtNDIwZS00ZDhhLWI3YmItMWRhMWM5ZmRmMzk4MjJkMGExMDItZDAxZi00MTZmLWIxYjctOTNmZWU2YjgzZDRi&redirect_uri=https%3a%2f%2fwww.office.com%2f&ui_locales=en-US&mkt=en-US:30] Cannot load stylesheet https://secure.aadcdn.microsoftonline-p.com/ests/2.1.8233.17/content/cdnbundles/converged.v2.login.min_jumzhgrnvlj7lwxqltrteq2.css. Failed integrity metadata check.
Console: [https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/authorize?client_id=4345a7b9-9a63-4910-a426-35363201d503&response_mode=form_post&response_type=code+id_token&scope=openid+profile&state=OpenIdConnect.AuthenticationProperties%3d5xhL9s5iN_65agH7ctGnRfQlJHUHgSrEvD4vkaO323RyB1klBHD6Qh5qidm6GuaIHM8_GaSANKH6y1ohWHalX4QU_YyqGJqXV8wphi2TVMAAY3yyXQk3GB-yqWm0j3oh&nonce=636748812038183968.MmMxNjY2YjEtNDIwZS00ZDhhLWI3YmItMWRhMWM5ZmRmMzk4MjJkMGExMDItZDAxZi00MTZmLWIxYjctOTNmZWU2YjgzZDRi&redirect_uri=https%3a%2f%2fwww.office.com%2f&ui_locales=en-US&mkt=en-US:30] Cannot load stylesheet https://secure.aadcdn.microsoftonline-p.com/ests/2.1.8233.17/content/cdnbundles/converged.v2.login.min_jumzhgrnvlj7lwxqltrteq2.css. Failed integrity metadata check.
Console: [https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/authorize?client_id=4345a7b9-9a63-4910-a426-35363201d503&response_mode=form_post&response_type=code+id_token&scope=openid+profile&state=OpenIdConnect.AuthenticationProperties%3d5xhL9s5iN_65agH7ctGnRfQlJHUHgSrEvD4vkaO323RyB1klBHD6Qh5qidm6GuaIHM8_GaSANKH6y1ohWHalX4QU_YyqGJqXV8wphi2TVMAAY3yyXQk3GB-yqWm0j3oh&nonce=636748812038183968.MmMxNjY2YjEtNDIwZS00ZDhhLWI3YmItMWRhMWM5ZmRmMzk4MjJkMGExMDItZDAxZi00MTZmLWIxYjctOTNmZWU2YjgzZDRi&redirect_uri=https%3a%2f%2fwww.office.com%2f&ui_locales=en-US&mkt=en-US:30] Failed to load external resource ['https://secure.aadcdn.microsoftonline-p.com/ests/2.1.8233.17/content/cdnbundles/converged.v2.login.min_jumzhgrnvlj7lwxqltrteq2.css']
Console: [null:0] Cannot load script https://secure.aadcdn.microsoftonline-p.com/ests/2.1.8233.17/content/cdnbundles/oldconvergedlogin_pcore.min_lwozjqawrstmtzsn2yunha2.js. Failed integrity metadata check.
Console: [null:0] Cannot load script https://secure.aadcdn.microsoftonline-p.com/ests/2.1.8233.17/content/cdnbundles/convergedloginpaginatedstrings-en.min_uzcugprrg6vz0z16am4meq2.js. Failed integrity metadata check.
Console: [null:0] Cannot load script https://secure.aadcdn.microsoftonline-p.com/ests/2.1.8233.17/content/cdnbundles/oldconvergedlogin_pcore.min_lwozjqawrstmtzsn2yunha2.js. Failed integrity metadata check.
Console: [null:0] Cannot load script https://secure.aadcdn.microsoftonline-p.com/ests/2.1.8233.17/content/cdnbundles/convergedloginpaginatedstrings-en.min_uzcugprrg6vz0z16am4meq2.js. Failed integrity metadata check.
Console: [null:0] Cannot load script https://secure.aadcdn.microsoftonline-p.com/ests/2.1.8233.17/content/cdnbundles/oldconvergedlogin_pcore.min_lwozjqawrstmtzsn2yunha2.js. Failed integrity metadata check.
Console: [https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/authorize?client_id=4345a7b9-9a63-4910-a426-35363201d503&response_mode=form_post&response_type=code+id_token&scope=openid+profile&state=OpenIdConnect.AuthenticationProperties%3d5xhL9s5iN_65agH7ctGnRfQlJHUHgSrEvD4vkaO323RyB1klBHD6Qh5qidm6GuaIHM8_GaSANKH6y1ohWHalX4QU_YyqGJqXV8wphi2TVMAAY3yyXQk3GB-yqWm0j3oh&nonce=636748812038183968.MmMxNjY2YjEtNDIwZS00ZDhhLWI3YmItMWRhMWM5ZmRmMzk4MjJkMGExMDItZDAxZi00MTZmLWIxYjctOTNmZWU2YjgzZDRi&redirect_uri=https%3a%2f%2fwww.office.com%2f&ui_locales=en-US&mkt=en-US:30] Failed to load external resource ['https://secure.aadcdn.microsoftonline-p.com/ests/2.1.8233.17/content/cdnbundles/oldconvergedlogin_pcore.min_lwozjqawrstmtzsn2yunha2.js']
Console: [null:0] Cannot load script https://secure.aadcdn.microsoftonline-p.com/ests/2.1.8233.17/content/cdnbundles/convergedloginpaginatedstrings-en.min_uzcugprrg6vz0z16am4meq2.js. Failed integrity metadata check.
Console: [https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/authorize?client_id=4345a7b9-9a63-4910-a426-35363201d503&response_mode=form_post&response_type=code+id_token&scope=openid+profile&state=OpenIdConnect.AuthenticationProperties%3d5xhL9s5iN_65agH7ctGnRfQlJHUHgSrEvD4vkaO323RyB1klBHD6Qh5qidm6GuaIHM8_GaSANKH6y1ohWHalX4QU_YyqGJqXV8wphi2TVMAAY3yyXQk3GB-yqWm0j3oh&nonce=636748812038183968.MmMxNjY2YjEtNDIwZS00ZDhhLWI3YmItMWRhMWM5ZmRmMzk4MjJkMGExMDItZDAxZi00MTZmLWIxYjctOTNmZWU2YjgzZDRi&redirect_uri=https%3a%2f%2fwww.office.com%2f&ui_locales=en-US&mkt=en-US:30] Failed to load external resource ['https://secure.aadcdn.microsoftonline-p.com/ests/2.1.8233.17/content/cdnbundles/convergedloginpaginatedstrings-en.min_uzcugprrg6vz0z16am4meq2.js']
```

**The above will also show you the HTML that was loaded. It is too long to add.**

Some code from [here](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360000616624-Problem-with-JavaFX-WebView-about-Access-Control-Allow-Origin) to help troubleshoot the problem.

I do not have Java 10. I used Java 8.

Comment: It's very useful and I get the same output like you, but does anyone have idea how to solve this? How to load this scripts?

Comment: I started a bounty. Maybe someone who is more knowledgeable will come and help.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that web view is using webkit engine for mac os/ linux os and IE engine for windows machines. WebView on mac os is working fine but there is problem on windows machines. When I was investigating this issue I find out that there is problem in this IE engine. I have access to few machines with different version of IE 11 installed on. On machines with update version 11.0.85 I wasn't able to open this site, but when I tried on machine with update version 11.0.90 the problem doesn't exist anymore. So if someone is using Windows OS please try to update IE version maybe it will solve problem.

Comment: This solution does not work on Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 1.8.0_171-b11. I just tried it.

Comment: JavaFX WebView is NOT using the IE engine on Windows.  It uses WebKit everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue and I think I found the critical point: external script/link integrity fails.
This is not a platform browser issue, JavaFX (OpenJFK) relies on an embedded webkit engine.

The regression happened between version 40 and version 172 on windows JDK 8.
It's working fine with Oracle JDK 9.0.4
It's not working with Oracle JDK 11

More details at:
https://github.com/mguessan/davmail/issues/12

Issue similar to: [Javafx - open login.microsoftonline.com page in webview component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52747674/javafx-open-login-microsoftonline-com-page-in-webview-component/53617567#53617567)

=> Updated answer: implemented to override Microsoft form content and disable integrity check. This is not a fix of the webkit bug, just a workaround

```
try {
    URL.setURLStreamHandlerFactory(new URLStreamHandlerFactory() {
        @Override
        public URLStreamHandler createURLStreamHandler(String protocol) {
            if ("https".equals(protocol)) {
                return new sun.net.www.protocol.https.Handler() {
                    @Override
                    protected URLConnection openConnection(URL url, Proxy proxy) throws IOException {
                        System.out.println("openConnection " + url);

                        if (url.toExternalForm().endsWith("/common/handlers/watson")) {
                            System.out.println("Failed: form calls watson");
                        }
                        final HttpsURLConnectionImpl httpsURLConnection = (HttpsURLConnectionImpl) super.openConnection(url, proxy);
                        if ("login.microsoftonline.com".equals(url.getHost())
                                && "/common/oauth2/authorize".equals(url.getPath())) {

                            return new URLConnection(url) {
                                @Override
                                public void connect() throws IOException {
                                    httpsURLConnection.connect();
                                }

                                public InputStream getInputStream() throws IOException {
                                    byte[] content = readFully(httpsURLConnection.getInputStream());
                                    String contentAsString = new String(content, "UTF-8");
                                    System.out.println(contentAsString);
                                    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                                    baos.write(contentAsString.replaceAll("integrity", "integrity.disabled").getBytes("UTF-8"));
                                    return new ByteArrayInputStream(baos.toByteArray());
                                }

                                public OutputStream getOutputStream() throws IOException {
                                    return httpsURLConnection.getOutputStream();
                                }

                            };

                        } else {
                            return httpsURLConnection;
                        }
                    }

                };
            }
            return null;
        }
    });
} catch (Throwable t) {
    System.out.println("Unable to register custom protocol handler");
}
```