# JavaFX WebView not displaying certain website

Tags: java, javafx, kotlin

I'm trying to display this site (https://www.nightdev.com/hosted/obschat/?theme=bttv_blackchat&channel=twitchpresents&bot_activity=false&prevent_clipping=true) in a javaFX WebView but when I load it it just displays a blank page and nothing ever happens, but when I tell it to go to https://stackoverflow.com/ it will just display the page as normal, I also used [JavaFX WebView can't load certain sites](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30784763/javafx-webview-cant-load-certain-sites) to get any possible errors that crop up but none are showing in my console, what's going wrong here?

```
fun main(args: Array<String>)
{
    Application.launch(ChatOverlay::class.java, *args)
}

class ChatOverlay : Application()
{
    override fun start(primaryStage: Stage?)
    {
        var primaryStage = Stage()
        val fxmlLoader = FXMLLoader()
        val root = fxmlLoader.load<Parent>(javaClass.getResource("/chat.fxml").openStream())
        primaryStage.initStyle(StageStyle.UNDECORATED)
        val scene = Scene(root, 400.0, 600.0)
        primaryStage.scene = scene
        primaryStage.isAlwaysOnTop = true
        primaryStage.show()
    }
}

class ChatOverlayController: Initializable
{
    override fun initialize(location: URL?, resources: ResourceBundle?)
    {
        print(webView.engine.isJavaScriptEnabled)
        GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.Main) {
            checkForWebengineError()
            webView.engine.load("https://www.nightdev.com/hosted/obschat/?theme=bttv_blackchat&channel=twitchpresents&bot_activity=false&prevent_clipping=true") }

}

fun checkForWebengineError()
{
    webView.engine.loadWorker.stateProperty().addListener{ _, _, _ ->
        var exception = webView.engine.loadWorker.exceptionProperty()
        println(exception)
    }
}

@FXML
lateinit var webView: WebView

}
```

FXML:

```
<?import javafx.scene.web.WebView?>


<WebView fx:id="webView" prefWidth="400.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/10.0.1" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="ChatOverlayController" />
```

Console output:

```
 true
 ReadOnlyObjectProperty [bean: javafx.scene.web.WebEngine$LoadWorker@4c03241a, name: exception, value: null]
 ReadOnlyObjectProperty [bean: javafx.scene.web.WebEngine$LoadWorker@4c03241a, name: exception, value: null]
 ReadOnlyObjectProperty [bean: javafx.scene.web.WebEngine$LoadWorker@4c03241a, name: exception, value: null]
```

Comment: You can use ideas from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52747674/javafx-open-login-microsoftonline-com-page-in-webview-component) to get a deeper look.